# Gitlab GKE Tutorial with free GCP fails: "CPUS_ALL_REGIONS": request requires '36.0' and is short '4.0' / How to config?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the [Gitlab GKE Tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/clusters/connect/new_gke_cluster.html#create-a-google-gke-cluster), which uses the [gitlab-terraform-gke project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/configure/examples/gitlab-terraform-gke.git)

I'm reaching the [deployment stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/clusters/connect/new_gke_cluster.html#provision-your-cluster) where the deployment fails with the error

```
│ Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 403: 
Insufficient project quota to satisfy request: 
resource "CPUS_ALL_REGIONS": request requires '36.0' and is short '4.0'. 
project has a quota of '32.0' with '32.0' available.
```

I'm not able to find configuration how to reduce the 36 to 32.
Do you have information how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deploying a regional cluster and the way [`node_count`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/configure/examples/gitlab-terraform-gke/-/blob/master/variables.tf) works is that specifies how many nodes to deploy **PER ZONE**. And because us-central1 has 3 zones, you're deploying a cluster with 9 nodes.  The node `machine_type` is `n1-standard-4`, which is a 4vCPU node, so 9 x 4vCPUs = 36 and that exceeds your quota.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. reduce the `node_count` and/or `machine_type`.  I don't know what the demo runs or if you even need that many nodes, but from a cost optimization perspective, if you don't need that many resources, don't deploy that many resources

(i.e. `node_count=2`, `machine_type=n1-standard-2` would mean you're now deploying 6 nodes total of 2vCPUs each for a total of 12vCPUs)

2. if you do need that many resources, contact GCP support and up your quota

EDIT: just wanted to mention that I maintain my own repo of Terraform deployment code for a cheap GKE cluster and I explain how it all works.  You can check it out [here](https://github.com/Neutrollized/free-tier-gke) if it interests you.

Comment: was reading through your repo - very helpful, thanks for your work!